# How do I unzip a password protected zip file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the code.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 

file_name = "XYZ.zip"

with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip: 
    zip.printdir()
    print('Extracting all the files now...') 
    zip.extractall(pwd=b'123123$SADMK6%002#')
    print('Done!')
```

This throws an error:

> NotImplementedError: compression type 99

The works file when its not password protected. Its only when I try to unzip the password protected file is when I get this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: how did you produce the file? (there are different types of zip encryption).

Comment: I am not sure. I got the zip from from another source. Is there a way to check the zip encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or other zip file extractor. there is different type of zip encryption so you can only unzip if the encryption method is same.

first install 7zip and add it's path to the environment variable on windows. Then run this code.

This piece of code helped me:

```
import subprocess
passwd = "asdf"
file_name = "F:\\test.zip"
output_path = "F:\\test"
subprocess.call(["7z", "x", '-p{}'.format(passwd), file_name,"-o"+output_path])
```

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the code. I am a  beginner to python.

Comment: When i ran the code i got the error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Yatish I edited answer. now look. Still having problem?

Comment: I tried to add the path, however i still get the same error.

Comment: ScreenCapture of the Enviornment Variable https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Afd1xxkRRZWrA3mnY99szG_hkVK1_UAW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: go `cmd` and type `7z` see if 7z run or not

Comment: yes it does https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bWTi0_Rg1A9L54J6qzvOtocxihOlwk0W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Its something to do with the zipfile name. I have the .py and zip placed in the same folder currently.

Comment: Mine is working fine. they are in same the folder. `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] ` this error give if it can't find the application you are looking..

Comment: Its working now, not sure what the issue was. I restarted my PC and it worked. the question I now have is, if the .py file and the zip file are located in different folders, how do I excute that. I tried to change the file name to include teh full path like D:\TestPy\d.zip but this does nothing. No error nothing

Comment: @Yatish I changed my code. you need to add path like this  `D:\\TestPy\\d.zip` and a outpath where you want to store extracted file . If you find this helpful accept it thanks. :)

Comment: also you can use `r'D:\TestPy\d.zip'` then you noo need to use double \\

Answer (score 4):

If you rather prefer a solution within Python, you can use this code instead

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 

file_name = "XYZ.zip"
with ZipFile(file_name, "r") as zip:
    zip.extractall(path="uncompressed", pwd="password".encode("utf-8"))
```

Alternatively, you can also tranfer the password in binary format - I am not sure why your code did not work, it succeeded for me in both cases (of course, do not forget to replace `password`).